# Sns scraper code - alteration for date range and maximum tweet count

Tags: python, web-scraping, tweets

```
  # importing libraries and packages
    import snscrape.modules.twitter as sntwitter
    import pandas
    import time
    import pandas as pd
    
    
    
    # Creating list to append tweet data 
    ManUtd_list = []
    
    # Using TwitterSearchScraper to scrape data and append tweets to list
    for i,tweet in enumerate(sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper('Man Utd since:2020-12-31 until:2021-01-02').get_items()): 
        if i>10000: #number of tweets you want to scrape
            break
        ManUtd_list.append([tweet.date, tweet.id, tweet.content, tweet.user.username]) #declare the attributes to be returned
        
    # Creating a dataframe from the tweets list above 
    ManUtd_df = pd.DataFrame(ManUtd_list, columns=['Datetime', 'Tweet Id', 'Text', 'Username'])
```

I am looking to scrape 10,000 tweets a day for these date range, how can I encode it so that the scraper loops through each date specified in the range and retrieves a maximum of 10000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing data ranges is easy, just `filter` the result (generator) by the `data` attribute. Here is a working example:

```
import snscrape.modules.twitter as sntwitter
import itertools
import multiprocessing.dummy as mp # multithreading 
import datetime

start_date = datetime.datetime(2023,2,15,tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)

def get_tweets(username,n_tweets = 100):
    tweets = itertools.islice(sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper(f'from:{username}').get_items(),n_tweets) # invoke the scrapper
    tweets = filter(lambda t:t.date>=start_date, tweets)
    tweets = map(lambda t: (username,t.date,t.url,t.rawContent),tweets) # keep only attributes needed
    tweets = list(tweets) # the result has to be pickle'able
    return tweets

# a list of accounts to scrape
user_names = ['kevin2kelly','briansolis','PeterDiamandis','Richard_Florida']

# parallelise queries for speed ! 
with mp.Pool(4) as p:
    results = p.map(get_tweets, user_names)
    
# combine results
results = list(itertools.chain(*results))
```